# How to fix overflow data labels in graph created with Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, charts

I have a graph created with Chart.js. There are options and one of them 'responsive: true' that provides a responsive view. The problem is when I load a graph with data the first time the y-ax labels overflow border and show as on the screen below. When I change the view y-ax labels show with overflow hidden and elepsis at the end of the label.
Also, I need to add a custom baloon for labels, how can I do it?
Before view change:

[image]

After view change:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my chank of code:

```
    drawWordsChart: function(placeholder, data, options = {}) {
        console.log('drawWordsChart', data);
        var sortable = [];
        for (var word in data) {
            sortable.push([data[word].text, data[word].weight]);
        }
        sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b[1] - a[1];
        });
        sortable = sortable.slice(0, 20);

        let labels = [];
        let values = [];
        let colors = [], intense = 1;
        angular.forEach(sortable, (elem, key) => {
            colors.push('rgb(30, 144, 255,' + (intense - key / 20) + ')');
            labels.push(elem[0]);
            values.push(elem[1]);
        });

        var horizontalBarChartData = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: options.label || 'weight',
                backgroundColor: colors,
                borderColor: colors,
                data: values
            }]

        };

        const ctx = document.getElementById(placeholder).getContext('2d');
        const myHorizontalBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: options.type || 'horizontalBar',
            data: horizontalBarChartData,
            options: {
                elements: {
                    rectangle: {
                        borderWidth: 1,
                    }
                },
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        barPercentage: 0.1,
                        barThickness: 10,
                        maxBarThickness: 10,
                        minBarLength: 2,
                        gridLines: {
                            offsetGridLines: true
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                return $filter('limitTo')(value, 8) + (value.length > 8 ? '...' : '');
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                },
                maintainAspectRatio: false
            }
        });
        return myHorizontalBar;
    }
```

Here I added property 'ticks' in options with callback, which limiting value to 8 letters, and add ellipsis at the end. Also, I added a custom filter.

```
ticks: {
 callback: function(value, index, values) {
  return $filter('limitTo')(value, 8) + (value.length > 8 ? '...' : '');
 }
}
```